# Is there a way to force an object to free memory in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I'm working on an iOS app with two different view controllers and three different views. The first view controller has just one view, which is a menu kind screen. The other view controller has two views, both of which display content heavily (videos, images, sounds, etc.). The problem is that the second view of this view controller absolutely has to deallocate ALL of it's objects, when dismissed, and it's not. There is an object from another class (a custom video player) that is not being deallocated, and that's causing the app to act erratically. I know it is not being deallocated because some of it's objects are still alive in memory, so, before I go through the whole code (1500+ lines of code) looking for objects that MIGHT not free when I want, is there a way to force the object to free it's memory? like a flush or something?

Comment: I'm not sure I got it: Do you think, you have done everything regarding memory management in your code you can do and the framework does something wrong or do you think you missed to release some objects and don't want to go through the whole code to look up which object it could be?

Comment: The recommended way from apple is to release your objects manually if you know their scope that when they are useless for you, but if you don't then use `autoreleasepool` for every scope. It will minimize your object leaks and increases the performance.

Comment: The most common kind of error is not releasing objects after you add them to an NSArray, NSDictionary, or pushing Views.  You can also run Analyze in XCode 4 (maybe 3.2?) with cmd+shift+B.  This will tell you where potential leaks may occur.  Make sure every `init` or `retain` is paired with a `release`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a crude test, you could call `dealloc` on your video player object, which will free it from memory. If some other object is still using it, your app will crash when that object tries to send it a message. When that happens, you could look at the stack trace to gain more information about what is hanging onto it. The Instruments app could also help you here.

Answer (score 1):

The memory for an object is freed immediately when it is `dealloc`-ed.  When you `release` an object, and it's retain count reaches zero, `dealloc` is called automatically.  If you have objects that are still in memory after you release them, it is likely that they are either over-retained or some other object (like the autorelease pool) is still retaining them.